# show most viewed posts of last days by link?

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, order, views

I use this link to get most viewed posts:

```
http://mydomain.com/?post_type=movies&meta_key=post_views_count&orderby=meta_value&order=ASC
```

But that gives me ALL posts from this post type in order of the most viewed - but I'd like to have only the latest most viewed posts from that custom post type of e.g.. 30 days.

How could I handle this?

thank you!

AD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this plugin : [WP Most Popular](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-most-popular) ?

> You can display popular posts from the last day, 7 days, 30 days or all time.

From the "Other notes" page :

> **Usage**
>
> There are two ways in which you can use this plugin.
>
> 1. As a sidebar widget
> 2. Custom function in your theme files
>
> Using the widget is the easiest way and recommended for most users. If you are a developer and want to integrate the plugin in to your existing theme, then read the information below.
>
> Firstly, the main function which you will need to include in your theme to fetch the popular posts is called wmp_get_popular().
>
> You can pass that function the following parameters in array form:
>
> • limit (integer)
> The number of posts you would like to display i.e. 5
> Default: 5
>
> • post_type (string)
> The post type you would like to display
> Example: post
> Default: All post types
>
> • range (string)
> In what date range would you like to display popular posts in
> Accepted: all_time, monthly, weekly, daily
> Default: all_time
>
> Those are the current parameters that the plugin supports.
>
> Let's look at an example of how to display the most recent popular posts in a unordered list :

```
<?php
echo '<ul>';
$posts = wmp_get_popular( array( 'limit' => 10, 'post_type' => 'post', 'range' => 'all_time' ) );
global $post;
if ( count( $posts ) > 0 ): foreach ( $posts as $post ):
    setup_postdata( $post );
    ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title() ? get_the_title() : get_the_ID()); ?>"><?php if ( get_the_title() ) the_title(); else the_ID(); ?></a></li>
    <?php
endforeach; endif;
echo '</ul>';
?>
```